# algorithm for choosing best proxy ip from a list of proxy ips

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am crawling several websites say `site1, site2, ...., site100`. I use a list of proxy ips to crawl them lets say `ip1, ip2, ..., ip10`. Whenever i crawl any page from a site say `site5` i call a function `getProxyFor(site5)` that gives me the proxy ip i should be using to request a page from `site5`. `getProxyFor` checks return the proxy ip which has been used for `site5` the least number of times(i can additional conditions like how old the proxy is or how many total successful requests(combined for all sites) has it sent, etc). So the basic problem is

> From a list of items where each has a few properties, I want to choose
>   an item by querying on one or more of its properties

I could store all this data is rdbms like

```
IP     | Site     | Count 
ip1    |  s1      |  5
ip1    |  s2      |  9
ip2    |  s2      |  1
```

and do a query like `select ip from table order by count limit 1` (i could use limit 5 and then check those 5 ips for age and other stuff). But what if i dont want to use a sql database? What data structure should i use to query efficiently on such data

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [redis](http://redis.io) for this type of functionality.  Specifically, redis has [sorted sets](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set), which buys you the ability to get the IP used the least number of times (assuming you use the number of times an IP was used as the score for the key).

If you have a more complex set of criteria to use to determine which IP gets used next, you could compute the score of the key by making it a function of the criteria (assuming that the output of the function is a number).  E.g. `score = f(last_time_used, latency, number_of_times_used)`

Also, redis is stored in memory so it is *freaky fast* compared to a SQL.

Comment: That works in this case. But if i have more than a single scoring criteria for an ip, lets say average response time, i guess i would need to create multiple keys in redis for each site like `site1-count`, `site1-latency`, etc and fetch a few ips for all those keys to decide the winner. It works but something better?

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your comments.  Does that help?